# Let $E_1,E_2\subset B$ be closed subspaces of a Banach space with $E_1\cap E_2=0$, then can we combine functionals $f_1\in E_1^*$ and $f_2\in E_2^*$?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $E_1,E_2\subset B$ be closed subspaces of a Banach space such that $E_1\cap E_2=0$, and let $f_1\in E_1^*$ and $f_2\in E_2^*$ be functionals (that is, bounded linear maps), and set $E=E_1\oplus E_2\subset B$. Clearly we can extend $f_1$ and $f_2$ uniquely to a linear map $$f:E\to\mathbb{R}$$ but will this map be bounded?

I've reduced this problem to proving that for any sequence $x_n\in E_1$ and $y_n\in E_2$ such that $\lVert x_n\rVert,\lVert y_n\rVert\ge1$ for all $n$, we cannot have $$x_n+y_n\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0$$ which I know how to prove if one of the spaces is finite dimensional, but in general, I don't immediately see why this is obvious.

Comment: I presume you want $E_1\cap E_2=\{0\}$.

Comment: If $E$ is closed in $B$, then $E \cong E_1 \times E_2$, and everything is good. If $E$ isn't closed, then $f$ will usually not be continuous.

Comment: Why is it true that $E$ being closed implies $E\cong E_1\oplus E_2$?